# Do we use NULL or 0 for database?

Tags: database-design

I am new to database management system and I have a question...
Let's say I designed a staff relation/table. In the staff relation, there is a column named "Pay". Some staff members do not have pay, so my question is should I input a value of "NULL" or "0"? Both works but which one is better?

Comment: What is the column related to? Is there a Table "PaymentTypes" with fix Payments that can be referenced? Then there probably should be one that says "No Payment" and that should be referenced in that case.

Comment: `null` means you do not know the value (you don't know if it's 0,1, or 42). That is something different than 0 (zero). If that is "yes/no" flag  you should store that as a `boolean` (which only allows `true` and `false`) - maybe even defined as `not null` if you want to prevent the "I do not know" situation.

Answer (score 4):

NULL and zero have different meanings.  Consider the average pay.  We have 6 people, with pay 1 2, 3, 0, 0, and 0.  The average pay is 1  (six divided by six).

Or we have 6 people with pay 1, 2, 3, NULL, NULL, and NULL.  The average pay is 2  (six divided by three).  Which answer is more meaningful in your case?

Comment: if I have a value of MaxPlay = null and I query if MaxPlay<2 ? Should it be TRUE? or I should use 0?

Comment: The result of the MaxPlay<2 query will be Unknown.  Unknown is neither TRUE nor FALSE.  That's how SQL works.  Should it work differently?

Comment: BTW,  MaxPlay is never "equal to" null.  If it is null, it is not equal to anything.

Comment: I was reading https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-what-is-a-null-value/ truth table from this link. Can we then make a truth table with unknown then?

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

You clearly have a case of "not applicable", this per your own sentence "Some staff members do not have pay".

Using NULL for "not applicable" is an even worse idea than is using it for "[applicable but] not known".  "Unknown" is what SQL *intended* it to be used for and using it for "unknown" you would "benefit" even if only in the sense of not incurring all the punishments SQL will pour over you if you do the theoretically sound thing, which is to split into two tables.

Suppose it really can be the case that someone who *does* have a pay, but that pay itself is unknown.  How are you going to record that and distinguish it from the case of someone who really does not have a pay at all ?

Answer (score 1):

**NULL** in SQL:

1. means **no value** (non-value), or **unknown**.
2. could be either **empty**, meaningless, absence of a value.
3. It is a **placeholder** for a data value that is **not known** or **not specified**, or **not even initialized**
4. The memory space is empty.
5. NULL can not be used in arithmetic operations (like + , - operators and aggregation operators count() or sum() and etc.).

**0** in SQL:

1. 0 is a numeric **value** by itself, **known quantity** of zero.
2. the 0 is not meaning empty, it is **known**, **specified** or **initialized** to known quantity of zero.
3. The memory space has value **0** stored in it.
4. **0** can be used in arithmetic operations.

For your question, **0** and **NULL** have not same meaning. **0** means that staff members **comes to pay action**, but he/she has payed **0** (maybe in some textbox or combo box he/she select the 0).

But, **NULL** means that he/she did not come to pay. Maybe in the next days he/she comes and pays some money. So **0** has different meaning and information than **NULL**.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to express:

- if this is a boolean (yes/no) type should be `BIT` or `TINYINT(1)` and the value 0 or 1
- if this contains a more complex value (like a FK to another table), `NULL` is a nice option

Comment: A boolean should be a `boolean` not a "bit" or some kind of integer.

Comment: "NULL is the best option" ... Well, I'd say in that case it depends. NULL may be *an* option but if it is *always* the best?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `boolean` and `bit` are aliases for `tinyint(1)`

Comment: That might be true for some databases that do not support a proper `boolean` type. But standard SQL does define a `boolean` type and that should be used. At least until XxS0ul678 reveals the actual DBMS that she/he uses. Also if you are thinking about MySQL then `tinyint(1)` is not a proper "boolean" replacement as it would still allow to store `42` or `114` in it.

Comment: after edit: "Null is a nice option" for what? It says "you don't know". For a Column about payments, I'd consider that an invalid entry. What should an accountant do with this? He could "assume" there is no salary, but that's not actually expressed by "NULL". Also, you are forcing the dev team to perform an explicit null-check: have fun talking to them ;)

Comment: @Fildor OP did a generic question (since he didnt specify anything about his specific case). That's why I gave him a generic answer that fits 99% of the designs

Comment: How do you come to that number? I don't say it's wrong, but I wouldn't be able to defend it with proof from the top of my head. I'd also argue that "NULL" is _never_ a good idea to represent a value other than "unknown" (with some rare exceptions, perhaps).

Comment: @Fildor 99% == most of the time (personal experience)